# Should we delete the [UX Designer] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I was about to weed through [ux-designer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ux-designer) and noticed there are more instances I'd need to remove than to leave (and it's not very common anyway).

This is one that pops up once in a while as a "can't think of what else" or "gotta add 5 tags" tag.

The tag description kinda gives it a purpose, but I think most questions related to UX Designer as a career would be better served in the [career-development](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career-development) tag (which should also be used sparsely-like half the first page of those are closed).

Should we clear this one out or how should we handle career-related questions in a way that doesn't result in the tag slapped on every question?